# error while parsing array using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting this weird error when i am trying to show the markers on map. and because of this map does not renders. everything working fine when passing other data. except this data.
please help

```
[
    ["Guiseley", "Unit 1", "Guiseley Retail Park", "Guiseley", "Leeds", "LS20 8QH", "01943878882", "5.6 miles", "england/guiseley/", "53.871101", "-1.7091662"],
    ["Batley - The Mill", "Unit HG2", "The Mill Discount Dept Store", "Bradford Road", "Batley", "WF17 5LZ", "01924 441066", "7.9 miles", "england/batley/", "53.7127707", "-1.6256998"],
    ["Ilkley", "6 Brook Street", " ", "Ilkley", "West Yorkshire", "LS29 8DA", "01943 605206", "9.3 miles", "england/ilkley/", "53.9248540", "-1.8229255"],
    ["Skipton", "29 High Street", " ", "Skipton", "North Yorkshire", "BD23 1DT", "01756 700043", "15.5 miles", " ", ","53.9619226"," - 2.0160739 "],
    ["Castleford - Junction 32 ","Unit A1 / 2 ","nction 32 Outlet Centre ","Carrwood Road ","Glasshowton ","WF10 4FR ","01977 514333 ","18.2 miles ","england / castleford / ","53.7120297 "," - 1.3394888 "]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Drop it in jsonlint.com

Comment: You have an unescaped double-quote in the second to last value of the second to last array.

Comment: I suggest not creating your own json, otherwise issues like this will happen. There are plenty of tools for each server-side language that will do it for you.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of `var` statements

Comment: hummmm ........ why so many downvote... I will be doing some research on this...

Comment: You got the downvotes because it's an incredibly trivial question, and the answer essentially boils down to "you screwed up." Some (small) amount of work on your part should have solved it for you.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: thats right mate... i did not know about the JSON Lint... and did try to find the errors in the array but got confused in the end..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 4):

Run it through [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and you see the error:

```
Parse error on line 51:
...    " ",        ","53.9619226","-2.0160
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```

Comment: thank you for providing info on JSON Lint....